# Extract document-topic matrix from Pyspark LDA Model

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, lda

I have successfully trained an LDA model in spark, via the Python API:

```
from pyspark.mllib.clustering import LDA
model=LDA.train(corpus,k=10)
```

This works completely fine, but I now need the *document*-topic matrix for the LDA model, but as far as I can tell all I can get is the *word*-topic, using `model.topicsMatrix()`.

Is there some way to get the document-topic matrix from the LDA model, and if not, is there an alternative method (other than implementing LDA from scratch) in Spark to run an LDA model that will give me the result I need?

EDIT:

After digging around a bit, I found the documentation for [DistributedLDAModel](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/DistributedLDAModel.html) in the Java api, which has a `topicDistributions()` that I think is just what I need here (but I'm 100% sure if the LDAModel in Pyspark is in fact a DistributedLDAModel under the hood...).

In any case, I am able to indirectly call this method like so, without any overt failures:

```
In [127]: model.call('topicDistributions')
Out[127]: MapPartitionsRDD[3156] at mapPartitions at PythonMLLibAPI.scala:1480
```

But if I actually look at the results, all I get are string telling me that the result is actually a Scala tuple (I think):

```
In [128]: model.call('topicDistributions').take(5)
Out[128]:
[{u'__class__': u'scala.Tuple2'},
 {u'__class__': u'scala.Tuple2'},
 {u'__class__': u'scala.Tuple2'},
 {u'__class__': u'scala.Tuple2'},
 {u'__class__': u'scala.Tuple2'}]
```

Maybe this is generally the right approach, but is there way to get the actual results?

Comment: I know that the LDA functionality in Spark is still in development, but it seems bizarre that there's no straightforward way of getting this info out of the model...

Comment: I think there is an another issue here. As pointed to me by [Jason Lenderman](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2480873/jason-lenderman) Spark LDA doesn't implement LSA but a variant of PLSI. It makes this matrices less useful directly. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953813/1560062

Comment: I see, but in that case a more or less equivalent solution would be to predict topics for the original training documents similar to the method described in the linked question, but as far as I can tell the necessary methods aren't implemented in the Python API. Are they hidden somewhere, or is there some other way of achieving this in Pyspark?

Comment: As far as I can tell it is not accessible from Python.

Comment: Looks like [this merged pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/12723) add the `topicDistributions` function.

Comment: is there an answer to this question with pyspark 2.0.0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After extensive research, this is definitely not possible via the Python api on the current version of Spark (1.5.1). But in Scala, it's fairly straightforward (given an RDD `documents` on which to train):

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.clustering.{LDA, DistributedLDAModel}

// first generate RDD of documents...

val numTopics = 10
val lda = new LDA().setK(numTopics).setMaxIterations(10)
val ldaModel = lda.run(documents)

# then convert to distributed LDA model
val distLDAModel = ldaModel.asInstanceOf[DistributedLDAModel]
```

Then getting the document topic distributions is as simple as:

```
distLDAModel.topicDistributions
```

Answer (score 5):

The following extends the above response for PySpark and Spark 2.0.

I hope you'll excuse me for posting this as a reply instead of as a comment, but I lack the rep at the moment.

I am assuming that you have a trained LDA model made from a corpus like so:

```
lda = LDA(k=NUM_TOPICS, optimizer="em")
ldaModel = lda.fit(corpus) # Where corpus is a dataframe with 'features'.
```

To convert a document into a topic distribution, we create a dataframe of the document ID and a vector (sparse is better) of the words.

```
documents = spark.createDataFrame([
    [123myNumericId, Vectors.sparse(len(words_in_our_corpus), {index_of_word:count}],
    [2, Vectors.sparse(len(words_in_our_corpus), {index_of_word:count, another:1.0}],
], schema=["id", "features"]
transformed = ldaModel.transform(documents)
dist = transformed.take(1)
# dist[0]['topicDistribution'] is now a dense vector of our topics.
```

Comment: can you share the full code that you use .. I am having issue in Pyspark and Spark 2.0 running hte transformed method.. (it is saying that it is not available)

Comment: Exactly what kinds of data is returned by transform into the dist object?  Are all the scala API outputs there, including topTopicsPerDocument, etc?  Why does it seem like we are the first humans to ever try using Spark's LDA? Might be best to avoid using this code completely....  It seems so alpha grade.

Comment: Apparently, the example code above works via Spark 2+.
Look at https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.clustering.LDA for more information.

Answer (score 3):

As of Spark 2.0 you can use `transform()` as a method from `pyspark.ml.clustering.DistributedLDAModel`. I just tried this on the 20 newsgroups dataset from scikit-learn and it works. See the returned `vectors` which is a distribution on topics for a document.

```
>>> test_results = ldaModel.transform(wordVecs)
Row(filename='/home/jovyan/work/data/20news_home/20news-bydate-test/rec.autos/103343', target=7, text='I am a little confused on all of the models of the 88-89 bonnevilles.\nI have heard of the LE SE LSE SSE SSEI. Could someone tell me the\ndifferences are far as features or performance. I am also curious to\nknow what the book value is for prefereably the 89 model. And how much\nless than book value can you usually get them for. In other words how\nmuch are they in demand this time of year. I have heard that the mid-spring\nearly summer is the best time to buy.', tokens=['little', 'confused', 'models', 'bonnevilles', 'someone', 'differences', 'features', 'performance', 'curious', 'prefereably', 'usually', 'demand', 'spring', 'summer'], vectors=SparseVector(10977, {28: 1.0, 29: 1.0, 152: 1.0, 301: 1.0, 496: 1.0, 552: 1.0, 571: 1.0, 839: 1.0, 1114: 1.0, 1281: 1.0, 1288: 1.0, 1624: 1.0}), topicDistribution=DenseVector([0.0462, 0.0538, 0.045, 0.0473, 0.0545, 0.0487, 0.0529, 0.0535, 0.0467, 0.0549, 0.051, 0.0466, 0.045, 0.0487, 0.0482, 0.0509, 0.054, 0.0472, 0.0547, 0.0501]))
```

Comment: Note to moderators, I deleted another post I created with this answer.

Comment: what is wordVecs in your example?