# Interpretation of Spark MLLib LDA results

Tags: apache-spark, lda, apache-spark-mllib

I ran LDA on spark for a set of documents and observed that the values of topicMatrix, which represents the topic distribution over terms, are more than 1 like 548.2201, 685.2436, 138.4013... What does these values mean? Are these the logarithmic values of the distribution or something. How to convert these values to probability distribution values.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both models (i.e. `DistributedLDAModel` and `LocalLDAMoel`) the `topicsMatrix` method will, I believe, return (approximately, there's a bit of regularization due to the Dirichlet prior on topics) the expected word-topic count matrix. To check this you can take that matrix and sum up all the columns. The resulting vector (of length topic-count-size) should be approximately equal to the word counts (over all your documents.) In any case, to obtain the topics (probability distributions over words in your dictionary) you need to normalize the columns of the matrix returned by `topicsMatrix` so that each sums to 1.

I haven't tested it out fully, but something like this should work to normalize the columns of the matrix returned by `topicsMatrix`:

```
import breeze.linalg.{DenseVector => BDV}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg._

def normalizeColumns(m: Matrix): DenseMatrix = {
  val bm = Matrices.toBreeze(m).toDenseMatrix
  val columnSums = BDV.zeros[Double](bm.cols).t
  var i = bm.rows
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1; columnSums += bm(i, ::) }
  i = bm.cols
  while (i > 0) { i -= 1; bm(::, i) /= columnSums(i) }
  new DenseMatrix(bm.rows, bm.cols, bm.data)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But is there any documentation mentioning these things anywhere?

Comment: ok, thanks a lot. Also I wanted to check topic distribution for documents. i was trying ldamodel.topicdistribution() but it was showing it's not a member of spark library. Do u know how to find topic distributions for trained and new documents?

Comment: I assume you're using the newer online variational EM algorithm for fitting a `LocalLDAModel`. The `LocalLDAModel` does not keep around the topic distributions for each of the documents in the training set (though it does keep everything needed to compute it), so the no-arg version of the `topicDistributions` method is not supported (unlike DistributedLDAModel.) You can obtain the topic distributions for an `RDD` of documents (whether in or out of the training set) by using `ldaModel.topicDistributions(docs)`.

Comment: You might find this discussion useful as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604516/spark-mllib-lda-how-to-infer-the-topics-distribution-of-a-new-unseen-document/32953813#32953813

Comment: the output of topicdistribution is of type Array[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] ...any idea how to export this to a file in scala?

Comment: Also ldaModel.topicDistributions(docs) showing error that the function doesn't take any parameters. how to find topic distribution for new incoming documents?
this is the error:
error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Long, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector)] does not take parameters
       val docTopic = distLDAModel.topicDistributions(documents)

Comment: If you're using the `DistributedLDAModel` you first need to convert to `LocalLDAModel` using `toLocal` method, then you can call `topicDistributions(documents)` on that. The thread I provided above discusses precisely this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Normalize the columns of the matrix returned by topicsMatrix in pure scala

```
def formatSparkLDAWordOutput(wordTopMat: Matrix, wordMap: Map[Int, String]): scala.Predef.Map[String, Array[Double]] = {

// incoming word top matrix is in column-major order and the columns are unnormalized
val m = wordTopMat.numRows
val n = wordTopMat.numCols
val columnSums: Array[Double] = Range(0, n).map(j => (Range(0, m).map(i => wordTopMat(i, j)).sum)).toArray

val wordProbs: Seq[Array[Double]] = wordTopMat.transpose.toArray.grouped(n).toSeq
  .map(unnormProbs => unnormProbs.zipWithIndex.map({ case (u, j) => u / columnSums(j) }))

wordProbs.zipWithIndex.map({ case (topicProbs, wordInd) => (wordMap(wordInd), topicProbs) }).toMap

}
```

https://github.com/apache/incubator-spot/blob/v1.0-incubating/spot-ml/src/main/scala/org/apache/spot/lda/SpotLDAWrapper.scala#L237