# Spark MLlib LDA, how to print topics, showing top-weighted 10 terms for each of the new/unseen document?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using LDA algorithm in Spark 1.5. I first build a Distributed LDA model over training data and then later use that to evaluate it on a new/unseen data. I am using this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604516/spark-mllib-lda-how-to-infer-the-topics-distribution-of-a-new-unseen-document) to generate topic distributions over the unseen data.

```
newDocuments: RDD[(Long, Vector)] = ...
val topicDistributions = distLDA.toLocal.topicDistributions(newDocuments)
```

The idea is to print what are the main themes discussed in each of the new documents. How do I link the aforementioned topic distributions to the topics from the distributed model and for each of the new document show (1) top-weighted 10 terms for first 5 main topics (2) Which terms mentioned in the document are occurring within top-weighted K terms for first 5 main topics the new/unseen documents?